# How to load vfio driver before ahci driver with mkinitcpio?

Tags: vfio

Good morning all,

I'd want to attach to vfio driver **at boot** my secondary sata controller in a manjaro os (kernel 5.16.7).
Usually, I add the devices in /etc/modprobe.d/vfio.conf, for example:

```
options vfio-pci ids=10de:100c,10de:0e1a,1b4b:9230,15b3:6274,1106:3403
```

In this example, there is gpu audio and video (10de), the sata controller (1b4b), an infiniband card (15b3) and firewire (1106).

Then, I add the modules in /etc/mkinitcpio.conf:

```
MODULES=(vfio_pci vfio vfio_iommu_type1 vfio_virqfd)
```

making sure that modconf is in the HOOKS:

```
HOOKS=(modconf base udev autodetect block filesystems keyboard)
```

Finally I generate initramfs:

```
mkinitcpio -P
```

All quite good, devices are attached to vfio, except for the sata controller, which is attached to the ahci driver (if not in use by some vm).
If I start the kvm vm with the sata controller set to be passed through, vfio driver attaches to it, but that's not what I'd want: the goal is to attach that sata controller to vfio at boot (not attaching it to vfio "on the fly").

I found some instructions for other oses, for example here:
https://gist.github.com/kiler129/4f765e8fdc41e1709f1f34f7f8f41706

The op explains that ahci driver loads before vfio, but manjaro uses mkinitcpio and my issue is that I don't understand how to adapt/translate those instructions for my os.